# Sql for this query

Tags: mysql

Can someone tell me the Sql that this query runs?

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
            $category->addAttributeToFilter("Top_Menu" , array('eq' => '146'));
            $category->addAttributeToSelect('name','parent_id','entity_id','url');
            $category->setOrder("parent_id", "ASC");
            $category->load();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply find this yourself by adding a true as first param to ->load();

`public function load($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)`

Comment: Or you can do $categroy->getSelect()->__toString()